# Excel (or GSheet) table: count which value appears how often

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have an excel (2019) table with dates and country codes:

| date | country |
| --- | --- |
| 2023/03/21 | us |
| 2023/03/14 | br |
| 2022/12/24 | us |
| 2024/01/17 | de |

From this I want to produce a list of unique country codes with a count which country exists how often. For the above table that would be:

| country | count |
| --- | --- |
| br | 1 |
| de | 1 |
| us | 2 |

Once that's solved I would like to limit the rows being counted to those of a specific year.

(I am a software developer working with C++, Java, etc. but I am at wits end with Excel) I expected this task to be really simple but I am terribly failing.

Comment: `COUNTIFS()` or `COUNTIF()` function would do what you are asking for. Also `Pivot Table` or `Power Query` can be used as well here.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(countries,UNIQUE(B2:B5),
      HSTACK(countries,
             BYROW(countries,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(B2:B5, c)))
    )
)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, ttarchala. Unfortunately I work with Excel 2019. Several of the functions in your proposal are not available with Excel 2019.

Comment: Oh, OK, in the previous Excel versions it's also possible but much less straightforward with formulas. In this case I concur with the previous commenter - use a Pivot Table or Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to help OP since he uses Excel 2019, but for those who use Excel 365 beta (as of the date of this answer), [the new GROUPBY() function](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/new-aggregation-functions-in-excel-groupby-and-pivotby) will also work:

```
=GROUPBY(B2:B5,A2:A5,COUNT,0,0,-1)
```

The arguments basically mean: group dates by country, count the groups, don't total, don't use headers, sort in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can use the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=QUERY(B:B,"select B, count(B)
            where B is not null
            group by B
            label count(B) 'count'",1)
```

[image]